# php DOMDocument nodeName property returning '#text' with the nodeName

Tags: php, dom, html-parsing

I want to extract the content of body of a html page along with the tagNames of its child. I have taken an example html like this:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<h1>This is H1 tag</h1>
<h2>This is H2 tag</h2>
<h3>This is H3 tag</h3>
</body>
</html>
```

I have implemented the php code like below and its working fine.

```
$d=new DOMDocument();
$d->loadHTMLFile('file.html');
$l=$d->childNodes->item(1)->childNodes->item(1)->childNodes;
for($i=0;$i<$l->length;$i++)
{
echo "<".$l->item($i)->nodeName.">".$l->item($i)->nodeValue."</".$l->item($i)->nodeName.">";
}
```

This code is working perfectly fine, but when I tried to do this using foreach loop instead of for loop, the nodeName property was returning '#text' with every actual nodeName. 
Here is that code

```
$l=$d->childNodes->item(1)->childNodes->item(1)->childNodes;
foreach ($l as $li) {
    echo $li->childNodes->item(0)->nodeName."<br/>";
}
```

Why so?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In DOM, everything is a 'node'. Not just the elements (tags); comments and text between the elements (even if it's just whitespaces or newlines, which seems to be the case in your example) are nodes, too. Since text nodes don't have an actual node name, it's substituted with `#text` to indicate it's a special kind of node.

Apparently, text nodes are left out when manually selecting child nodes with the `item` method, but included when iterating over the `DOMNodeList`. I'm not sure why the class behaves like this, someone else will have to answer that.

Beside `nodeName` and `nodeValue`, a `DOMNode` also has a [`nodeType`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php#domnode.props.nodetype) property. By checking this property against [certain constants](http://php.net/manual/en/dom.constants.php) you can determine the type of the node and thus filter out unwanted nodes.

Comment: Discovered you can solve the DOM family nextSibling quarrel with nextElementSibling! Damn you ↵'s and <!-- comments -->

Answer (score 18):

When I've had this problem it was fixed by doing the following.

```
$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc->preserveWhiteSpace = false; // important!
```

You can trace out your $node->nodeType to see the difference.  I get 3, 1, 3 even though there was only one node (child).  Turn white space off and now I just get 1.

GL.

Answer (score 4):

I'm coming a little late to this but the best solution for me was different. The issue its that the TEXT node doesn't know it's name but his parent do so all you need to know it's ask his parent for the nodeValue to get the key.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($stringXML);
$valorizador = $dom->getElementsByTagName("tagname");
foreach ($valorizador->item(0)->childNodes as $item) {
  $childs = $item->childNodes;
  $key = $item->nodeName;
  foreach ($childs as $i) {
     echo $key." => ".$i->nodeValue. "\n";
  }
}
```